# Python bottle framework generating word document

Tags: python, bottle

I need to generate a word document on the server side using Python bottle framework.

Im using the Python-docx module to generate but not sure how can I do that...

This is how I generated

```
import StringIO
output = StringIO.StringIO()
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory':True})
output.seek(0)
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-                    officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=UTF-8'
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
return output.read()
```

but not sure how to integrate Python-docx to generate word document..

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you show us the code that isn't working, we can help you proceed.

Comment: you can generate a file and use static file to retrieve file for download